# React / React-Native Refs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, ref

I'm trying to give my custom component the option to use ref, but I'm not sure how to do it, what would be the best way to do that?

For example I have my component: `<InputField ref="email" />`

If I do `console.log` inside the InputField class, I get an empty `refs={}`

```
    <View style={ styles.wrapItems }>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.emailInput.onError() }>
     <Text>Show Error</Text></TouchableOpacity>
     <InputField ref={(ref) => this.emailInput } alignItems={'center'} placeholder="Your Email" />
     <InputField ref={(ref) => this.passwordInput } secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Your Password" />
</View>
```

Inside my Component

```
export default class InputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  static onError() {
    alert('On Error');
  }
return (
 <View style={ styles.inputWr }>
  <TextInput
   ref={??}
   style={ [styles.input, textDir, textColor] }
   onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
   keyboardType={keyboardType}
   underlineColorAndroid={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
   onFocus={this.onFloatLabel}
   secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
   value={this.state.text}
   onBlur={this.onFloatLabel} />
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Access the value of the input field?

Comment: @azium, I have a static function inside my component that I want to call it from outside but I need somehow to ref this Component.

Comment: Usually in React using refs means you're doing something wrong. Can you post your component with the static method and component you want to call it from? there's almost certainly a better way

Comment: @azium, I've just added a snippet. I'm not trying to do anything to crazy, haha.

Comment: What does the function you're trying to call do? The ref will be a reference to the element not the class, so static functions won't be available.

Comment: @TuckerConnelly it is just example, I will do the logic after. Anways, the function works fine, I can call it directly InputField.onError(), so there is no problem with the function. However I need to ref the component I want to call the function.

Comment: I just think you're taking the wrong approach here. Why can't that function live in the parent?

Comment: @azium because I want to show an error, for each input.. so if I type a wrong password for example, I will display the error bellow the TextInput , if I type a wrong email so I want to call error for the email input. If I had a global error msg yes.. I would call from parent.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the **ref** parameter to **this.emailInput**

```
<InputField ref={ref => this.emailInput = ref} alignItems={'center'} placeholder="Your Email" />
```

But take care using *refs*, normally it's not a good approach (sometimes props callbacks do the job).

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I changed the static function to a non-static one and it worked.

From:

```
static onError() {
```

To:

```
onError() {
```